# Random function with break command in Python

Tags: python, random

1. Write a function that accepts 3 numbers and calculates the average of the 3 numbers and raises the average to the second power (returns the average squared).
2. Write a loop that finds 3 random uniform numbers (0 to 1); sends the 3 numbers to the function and **stops the loop when the value of the function is greater than 0.5625**

I tried to figure out this 2 things but I am confused a little bit.

```
import random 

a = random.random ()
b = random.random ()
c = random.random ()

def avenum(x1,x2,x3):   # the average of the 3 numbers
    z = (x1+x2+x3)/3.0 
    return z

y = avenum(a,b,c)

print 'the average of the 3 numbers = ',y


def avesec(x1,x2,x3):   # the average of the second power
    d = ((x1**2)+(x2**2)+(x3**2))/3.0 
    return d

y1 = avesec(a,b,c)

print 'the average of the second power = ',y1
```

Comment: average squared would just be avenum(x1,x2,x3)**2 no? not sure what the second part of what you're asking is.

Comment: Note that the assignment asks for one function and you have two. Also note comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question:

> Write a function that accepts 3 numbers and calculates the average of the 3 numbers and raises the average to the second power (returns the average squared).

```
def square_of_average(x1, x2, x3):
    z = (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3
    return z ** 2 # This returns the square of the average
```

Your second question:

> Write a loop that finds 3 random uniform numbers (0 to 1); sends the 3 numbers to the function **and stops the loop when the value of the function is greater than 0.5625**.

Assuming you want to write this in another function:

```
import random
def three_random_square_average():
    z = 0 # initialize your answer
    while(z <= 0.5625): # While the answer is less or equal than 0.5625...
        # Generate three random numbers:
        a, b, c = random.random(), random.random(), random.random()
        # Assign the square of the average to your answer variable
        z = square_of_average(a, b, c)
    # When the loop exits, return the answer
    return z
```

Another option:

```
import random
def three_random_squared_average():
    while(True):
        a, b, c = random.random(), random.random(), random.random()
        z = square_of_average(a, b, c)
        if(z > 0.5625):
            break
    return z
```

If you don't want a function:

```
import random
z = 0
while(z < 0.5625):
    z = square_of_average(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
print z
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly for 1) - you're raising the average to the second power... not each value. Otherwise you want the average of the second powers of the input values.

```
import random 

a = random.random ()
b = random.random ()
c = random.random ()

def avenum1(x1,x2,x3):   # the average of the 3 numbers
    z = ((x1+x2+x3)/3.0)**2
    return z
```

For 2): There are better ways but this is the most obvious.

```
def avenum1(x1,x2,x3):   # the average of the 3 numbers
    z = ((x1+x2+x3)/3.0)**2
    return z

avg = 0:
while avg<0.5625:
    a = random.random ()
    b = random.random ()
    c = random.random ()
    avg = avenum1(a,b,c)
```

The better way:

```
avg = 0
while avg<0.5625:
    list_ = [random.random() for i in range(3)]
    avg = (sum(list_)/3.0)**2
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the built in type.